# Calling API before views load and saving json data to use in views

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I make an API call that returns data that I am to use to fill data used in a view. How would I go about making the call before the app opens, as well as using the data stored/returned by the getProducts() to use in other views.

I have a Codable struct that parses the JSON data that's called by the following code. The Codable data model and the following function are in a file called Loaders.

```
func getProducts() -> [ProductResponse]{
    var products: [ProductResponse] = []
    if let apiUrl = URL(string: "https://assessment-edvora.herokuapp.com") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: apiUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            do{
                let productsFromApi = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProductResponse].self, from: data!)
                products = productsFromApi
                print(products)
            }catch let err{
                print(err)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    return products
}
```

Currently the function is called as so, and the data is returned and parsed correctly.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Welcome")
            .onAppear(perform: {
               getProducts()
            })
    
    }
```

```
struct ProductCardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(color: Color(.sRGB, red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.5), radius: 4, x: -5, y: 5)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Text("products.id")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .bold()
                        .padding([.top, .leading])
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    Spacer()

                }
                Text("products.description")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .italic()
                    .padding(.leading)
                
                Spacer()
                Image("products.image")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```

The JSON data is an array of products. I want to display each product in a card using a ProductCard view, where in the Text field I want to use properties like product.description etc. I tried using ObservableObject in the Loaders file however being new with swift I am unsure where to proceed to learn up.

Ultimately each product card will be displayed in a horizontal scrollable list.

Answer (score 2):

Your single "source of truth" appears to be ContentView. You should use a ViewModel for this and observe it using @StateObject (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-stateobject-property-wrapper)

example view model:

```swift
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var products: [ProductResponse] // @Published notifies the view when it changes (once network call is done)
    func fetch() {
        // your existing code
    }
}
```

example usage:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ContentViewModel() // @StateObject subscribes to the changes (when network call finishes)
    var body: some View {
        Text("Welcome")
            .onAppear(perform: {
               vm.fetch()
            })
    
    }
```

In ContentView iterate over the products using `ForEach` and create a  `ProductCardView` for each. The idea is there should be no network call in the ProductCardView, pass the data in as an argument:

```swift
struct ProductCardView: View {
    let product: ProductResponse // this gets populated from the initializer (see below)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(color: Color(.sRGB, red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.5), radius: 4, x: -5, y: 5)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Text(product.id)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .bold()
                        .padding([.top, .leading])
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    Spacer()

                }
                Text(product.description)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .italic()
                    .padding(.leading)
                
                Spacer()
                Image(product.img) // you may need to find a solution to show image from network
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
ForEach(vm.products) { product in 
    ProductCardView(product: product) // pass it in
}
```

you can put that in whatever layout you want

As to loading the content *before* the app launches, have a look at background fetch. One approach is caching the json on disk.